# How to trigger a "button" in PowerApps upon hitting the "return" key in a TextInput

Tags: powerapps

I am having a quite easy application. I have a text input field and button to execute a task. The app works fine when the user enter some text in the text input field - and then click the button.

The problem is, that I want the button functionality to be executed every time a user enter the "Enter" key in the text input field. I tried to search for an answer but did not really find a solution, even if it should be quite common use case.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not yet supported by Microsoft Power Apps.

This is a known limitation of text input in Power Apps canvas application.

Check below links for more information and some workarounds:

1. [Using Enter to Search with input](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Using-Enter-to-Search-with-input/td-p/812847)
2. [Submit Form with the Enter Key](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Submit-Form-with-the-Enter-Key/td-p/835008)

Also, you can vote on this idea for implementing this feature in near future:

[Press enter to submit](https://ideas.powerapps.com/d365community/idea/e5ad9df1-89fb-4444-9dec-0b8abd7db76f)